# Sorting array goes beyond the size

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I wrote this program to sort pair of number based on the even subscript in ascending order. For example; "1,4,15,3" would be "15,3,1,4" after sorting. The sorting is working properly but, the problem I ran into was that the inner loop was comparing elements beyond the size of array. It is comparing against random number. I don't know the exact times the loop should run (I have tried size - 3). Please help me fix this error. Here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>

void ssort(int arr[], int arrSize)
{
    int j, k;
    bool flag;
    do
    {
        flag = false;   
        for (int i = 0; i <arrSize; i++)  //Runs 10 times
        {
            if (arr[i+1] > arr[i+3])      //compare the 2nd element with 4th
            {
                j = arr[i+2];  //j holds 3rd element
                k = arr[i+3];    //k holds 4th element

                arr[i+2] = arr[i];   //3rd element is now 1st element
                arr[i+3] = arr[i+1];    //fourth element is now 2nd element

                arr[i] = j;    //1st is now 3rd element
                arr[i+1] = k;  //2nd is now fourth element

                flag = true;
            }
        }
    }
    while (flag);

}
int main()
{

    int arr[10] = {1,5,2,15,10,4,15,23,16,15};
    std::cout <<"Unsorted array \n";
    for (int i: arr)
    {
        std::cout <<i <<" ";
    }
    std::cout <<"\n";
    ssort(arr,10);

    std::cout <<"Sorted \n";
    for (int i: arr)
    {
        std::cout <<i <<" ";     
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `flag` looks broken to me; if your input array is already sorted you will have an infinite loop because `flag` will never be set.

Comment: Take a look at the boundary conditions.  We know that `i` can get up to `arrSize - 1` in the loop, and you read as far as `arr[i+3]`, a.k.a. `arr[arrSize+2]`.

Comment: Another problem is that `i` can be every single index, but based on how you have described the sorting, it seems that you should only be looking at even values of `i`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always keep in mind to check the corner cases.
when you are adding constant value to index then addition should not cross array size-1.
Add the check and you handle the corner cases.